# neo4JClient returning empty nodes

Tags: neo4jclient

I am using neo4JClient to query a list of nodes in the graph and present them on the web browser as a table. In order to get data, the following code is used.

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Match("DataSpace")
    .Return(DataSpace => DataSpace.As<DataSpace>());
var longBooks = query.Results;
    jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(longBooks, Formatting.None, settings);
    context.Response.Write(jsonString);
```

The graph contains various other nodes.

```
 The Resultset at the Browser Window is : 
 [{"DataSpaceName":"DS1","DataSpaceDescription":"First Dataspace"},{"DataSpaceName":"DS2","DataSpaceDescription":"Second Dataspace"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

There are empty nodes that get returned, which I think correlates to the other nodes in the graph.

Can I get rid of the Empty Nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query returns all nodes because that's what you asked for. Your Neo4jClient query simply translates to this Cypher query:

```
MATCH DataSpace
RETURN DataSpace
```

In this case `DataSpace` is simply an identifier that represents every node, without additional constraints.

Do your DataSpace nodes have anything that separates them from other nodes, e.g. a label, a common node that they're all connected to, a unique property?

In case the nodes have a unique `DataSpace` label, you can for query them with:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Match("ds:DataSpace")
    .Return(ds => ds.As<DataSpace>());
```

In case `DataSpaceName` is a property that is only present on DataSpace nodes, you can try:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Match("ds")
    .Where("has(ds.DataSpaceName)")
    .Return(ds => ds.As<DataSpace>());
```